# Connected topological manifolds

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, connectedness

For any connected topological manifold, it is true that for any two points on the manifold, there exists a single local chart that both of two points lie in it.

How can I prove it?

Comment: Hint: Connected manifolds are path connected.

Comment: How does use it?

Comment: I think what you are looking for can be found here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/35780/given-two-points-in-a-manifold-can-one-always-find-a-topological-ball-that-cont

Comment: @user135988: I think the difficulty lies in the fact that the manifold is not assumed to have any differentiable structure...

Comment: @frog: Everything in that answer works fine, you just need to use locally flat paths as opposed to smooth ones.

Comment: @Mike: What do you mean by locally flat?

Comment: @frog [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_flatness).

Comment: Ok, I see now. Thanks for this input!